# SQLite query runs on SQLiteManager but not on iOS

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite

Having an sqlite issue. The query runs fine on the firefox addon SQLiteManager. It does not run on iOS however. I get an error code of 1. The database gets connected to fine.

```
NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"featureDB"
                                                     ofType:@"sqlite3"];

if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
    DLog(@"Failed to open database!");
} else {

    DLog(@"Connected to db");

}



NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM featureTable"];

sqlite3_stmt *statement;


NSLog(@"could not prepare statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));


if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

        DLog(@"row");

        int uniqueId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);



    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    DLog(@"sqliteStep");

} else {

    DLog(@"statement Error %d", sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil));

}
```

The log for "row or sqliteStep" never fires.

Comment: So what is the error message generated?  (Hint, read the spec.)

Comment: By the way, if you open DB from bundle, it's read-only. Is that your intent? Generally the app would look for db in documents folder and only if it's not found there would the app copy it from the bundle to the documents folder. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26325358/1271826. This is not the problem in your above routine, but just a FYI.

Answer (score 2):

Your `else` statement should not call `sqlite3_prepare_v2` again, but rather should:

```
DLog(@"prepare error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
```

What does this error message report?

Note: You already are logging `sqlite3_errmsg` before you call `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. Of course that's going to report no error, because no error could have possibly has taken place yet. Do this logging *inside* the `else` clause where you know `sqlite3_prepare_v2` (a) has been called; but (b) didn't return `SQLITE_OK`. And don't call any SQLite functions between when `sqlite3_prepare_v2` failed and where you log the error message.

The most common problem is that it reports that there is no such table. And if that's what you see, in this case that could be a result of failing to include the database in the app bundle (see the "Copy Bundle Resources" section of the "Build Phases" section of your target settings).

Alternatively, if it says something about the database is busy, that can happen if you have mismatched your database open calls and your database close calls (like you have in this code sample).

Comment: ah! I see now. It says no such table.

Comment: sqlite3_open_v2([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) returns SQLITE_OK, so I guess the table is misspelled? But how can that be if the query runs fine in other programs?

Comment: NSString *sqLiteDb is null, I think that's the problem

Comment: That means that it didn't find it in the bundle. I've mentioned it a couple of times, but have you checked the "Copy Bundle Resources" section of the "Build Phases" of your target in Xcode?!? That's the first thing to check when getting a "table not found" error when opening a database that you allegedly got from the bundle.

Comment: i did, and sadly it's there. It has an sqlite extension though. is that the right extension?

Comment: The extension doesn't matter, but it has to match what your code is looking for, which is `sqlite3` extension. If the file is really `sqlite` extension, change the code to match. Personally, I always use `sqlite` for my extension.

Answer (score 1):

please make sure your sqlite db is not opened with any sqlite db browser when you are running app in simulator. 
It happened with me, I had my sqlite db opened in sqlite browser to test my query and when I was running app from simulator it was not updating anything in db.

Comment: thanks! I don't think thats the problem unfortunately =/ I closed everything and it's still the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my file was of sqlite extension, but the code specified an extension of sqlite3. I thought the two were synonymous but they weren't